# How to avoid overlapping of html elements over each other?

Tags: html, css, overlap

I'm facing a problem creating something. I want a number of            `<kbd>` tag in my body which should be aligned right. I'm able to do so but the problem is that `<kbd>` elements are overlapping over each other. So I want to know that how can I keep the `<kbd>` elements right aligned and avoid their overlapping.

```css
.me_msg {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #003cff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1.1% 4% 1.1% 4%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 03%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<kbd class='me_msg'>My First Message</kbd>
<kbd class='me_msg'>My Second Message</kbd>
<kbd class='me_msg'>My Third Message</kbd>
```

Comment: 'kbd' ?? it's not html tag bro.

Comment: because '.me_msg' element's position is absolute in your style

Comment: @danish443 [It is.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use absolute, unless you want to position each button separately/manually.

A simple solution would be to float right instead.

```css
.me_msg {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #003cff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 1.1% 4% 1.1% 4%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #e9e9e9;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<kbd class='me_msg'>My First Message</kbd>
<kbd class='me_msg'>My Second Message</kbd>
<kbd class='me_msg'>My Third Message</kbd>
```

Comment: Actually I tried it before, to float the element to right. But im not getting the kbd elements vertically inline like a list. Im getting the elements as horizontally inline.

Comment: All right Im actually a beginner and this is first question im asking. So im lacking experience. Anyways thank you for your interference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo If I got you question right
I mean the css part

```
 .me_msg {
         background:rgb(250,250,250);
         border-radius:10px 10px 0px 10px;
         border-width:1px;
         color:#003cff;
         padding:10px;
         text-align:right;
         padding:1.1% 4% 1.1% 4%; 
             float: right;
             display: inline-block;
             bottom:auto;
         min-width:10%;     
             max-width:40%;
         box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #e9e9e9;
        }
```

Link https://jsfiddle.net/1uh3ha5w/